# Host multimedia content

Tags: web-hosting, storage

On the occasion of a new website, I'm looking for a reliable and inexpensive company to host a big volume of movies and pictures.

I need around 1To to start knowing that it will grow each day.

Do you have any company to advise ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Amazon S3 is storage for the Internet. It is designed to make web-scale computing easier for developers.
>
> Amazon S3 provides a simple web services interface that can be used to store and retrieve any amount of data, at any time, from anywhere on the web. It gives any developer access to the >same highly scalable, reliable, secure, fast, inexpensive infrastructure that Amazon uses to >run its own global network of web sites. The service aims to maximize benefits of scale and >to pass those benefits on to developers.

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/